# How to display WIFI setup menu from command line

Tags: wireless, command-line, lubuntu

Normally Wifi setup menu can be displayed by GUI(Preferences->Network Connections)
but I want to display Wifi setup menu from command line(type command then Wifi setup menu show on GUI).
My OS is Lubuntu 12.04.
Please suggest.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open it using `/usr/bin/nm-connection-editor`